# Neo4j: Create a graph with unique nodes using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a table of senders and receivers:

```
Table A:

+------+--------+                                                          
|sender|receiver|
+------+--------+ 
|     A|       B|
|     B|       C|
|     C|       D|
|     D|       A|
|     E|       B|
|     A|       D|
|     E|       C|
+------+--------+
```

I want to create a graph with connections from 'sender' to 'receiver'. For example, `A -(rel)-> B`

The values in the sender column can also appear in the receiver column. However, I do not want the nodes A,B,C,D, and E to be repeated in my graph. They must only appear once in the final graph.

I tried doing this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///graph' AS row
CREATE (:sender_node { sender: row.sender})

MATCH (n:sender_node)
WITH n.sender AS sender, collect(n) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
FOREACH (n in tail(nodes) | DELETE n)

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///graph' AS row
CREATE (:receiver_node { receiver: row.receiver})

MATCH (n:receiver_node)
WITH n.receiver AS receiver, collect(n) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
FOREACH (n in tail(nodes) | DELETE n)

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///graph' AS row
MATCH (from_var:sender_node {sender: row.sender}),(to_var:receiver_node {receiver:row.receiver})
CREATE (from_var)-[:rel]->(to_var)
RETURN *
```

I basically deleted the duplicates separately in sender and receiver nodes. But since the nodes A, B, C, and D appear in both 'sender' and 'receiver' columns, they appear twice in the graph. I want to correct this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start node of an `EMAILS` relationship is implicitly a sender. And the end node of an `EMAILS` relationship is implicitly a receiver. So you should not have different labels for the sender and receiver node, which is redundant and makes your data model overly complex.

Instead, you should just use, say, the `User` label for both kinds of nodes. That will also help you to avoid duplicates, especially when you use the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause instead of [CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/).

For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///graph' AS row
MERGE (sender:User {id: row.sender})
MERGE (receiver:User {id: row.receiver})
MERGE (sender)-[:EMAILS]->(receiver)
RETURN *
```